# How to add one double-quotes (") to string?

Tags: c#, mysql, request

I writing a request in C# for MySql Database and I need to write in string of the command double-quotes.
Something like:

```
 String command ="Insert into table (column) values ("" + textBox1.Text + "")";
```

But I have a syntax error of C#. When I try chenge " to `

```
 String command ="Insert into table (column) values ('" + textBox1.Text + "')";
```

I have a syntax error of Mysql(1054). Row column has a type varchar. How to correctly write this request in a program?

Comment: You need to use parameters.

Comment: @SLaks Can you give an example?

Comment: Escaping is done with a backslash.

Comment: @Dmytro Did you try my answer? it should work for you. But you really should not be doing this kind of stuff in an sql statement, it's very hackable.

Comment: @SLaks I just asked to show example, like answer in my question. But thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how:

```
string mystring = "We use \"a laser\"";
```

BUT! Since you are trying to form an sql query, you shouldn't do this yourself. You need to use sql parameters that will protect you from [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Here is a short lesson about sql parameters: http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson06